# No BoundingBox error message

Tags: graphics

I want to include an `eps` file in LaTeX. I typed the following in Texmaker

```
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The error I get is

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in figure.eps (no BoundingBox).
```

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What is the filename extension of your graphics file? Is it .eps, or something else? Please advise.

Comment: does you figure have a bounding box (a line like `%%BoundingBox: 1 2 3 4`) It should have if it is a valid EPS file.

Comment: As @David Carlisle is saying; try opening your `figure.eps` in a _text_editor_ and search for the word: `BoundingBox`. If it is not there, then something is wrong. What is the source of your figure?

Comment: in some .eps files, the bounding box information is at the end, rather than at the beginning where it really belongs.  (and latex won't find it at the end.)  with more specific information, someone here can give instructions on how to repair it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton it should find it at the end, that's the plan anyway

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- we've had problems here in production with the bounding box at the end; maybe it's `dvips` that can't find it properly, but in any case, we always have to make repairs.  so i made an assumption ...

Comment: What do you get with `\includegraphics[bb=0 0 100 100]{figure}` ?

Comment: Also, I encountered the same problem. In my case, I had *dots* in the filename.
e.g. `abc.def.png`

Answer (score 16):

Although the question has been answered by @DavidCarlisle in the comment, I'll try to complete the answer here.

This is not supposed to happen for valid `eps` files, as they should contain a `BoundingBox` comment and the `graphicx` package should be able to read it.  The error message is typical when including bitmap graphics, e.g. `jpg`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731933/error-including-image-in-latex).

In case you have a peculiar `eps` file which contains a `BoundingBox` comment but, for some reason, `graphicx` cannot read it, you can try searching your file.  Do this either by opening the file in a text editor or by using something like the `grep` command:

```
grep BoundingBox figure.eps
```

You should normally see a line like:

```
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 30 30
```

Then, update your `\includegraphics` by supplying that:

```
\includegraphics[scale=1,bb=0 0 30 30]{figure}
```

In case you cannot find a bounding box (and your `eps` file is still usable, of course, which may not be the case), I'd suggest that you try guessing it.  Start, e.g. with `bb=0 0 100 100` and see what you get, then try increasing or decreasing the numbers.  They are, in turn: lower-left-x (`llx`), lower-left-y (`lly`), upper-right-x (`urx`), and upper-right-y (`ury`).  The width of the picture is `urx-llx` and the height is `ury-lly`.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error occur too. In my case it turned out that I had a file named `figure.eps.pdf`, and so the `\includegraphics` command (which apparently tries to guess the file ending) tried to load that instead of `figure.eps`. Deleting the file `figure.eps.pdf` solved my problem.

Comment: This does not seem to be an answer, because it does not explain what you did to resolve the problem.

Comment: It does now....

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
```

That solved my problem in any format .png, pdf, ps, eps...

Comment: Why the downvote? this worked for me.