# Overleaf No Bounding Box Error

Tags: bounding-box

I am using Overleaf V2 and just received the following error message:

[image: No Bounding Box Error Message]

This topic has been dealt with here: [No BoundingBox error message](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133786/no-boundingbox-error-message)

But I am new to this and don't understand how to check the eps information they refer to there. I have png and jpg image files contained with a folder "Pictures". The error comes up for both file types.

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    includeheadfoot,
    top = 20mm,
    left = 25mm,
    right = 20mm, 
    bottom = 30mm,
    bindingoffset = 5mm,
    }

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{LCA}
\chead{}
\rhead{Daniel Wilkinson}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
%\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[english, norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{url}
%% The font package uses mweights.sty which has som issues with the
%% \normalfont command. The following two lines fixes this issue.
\let\oldnormalfont\normalfont
\def\normalfont{\oldnormalfont\mdseries}
%\usepackage{Chivo}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%START DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\title{Master Thesis}
\author{DW}
\date{\today}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}


\maketitle

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables


\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.62}


\include{acknow}

\include{abstract}

\include{summary}

\include{abbreviations}

\include{symbols}

\include{intro}
\include{background}

\include{literature}

\include{method}

\include{Calculations}
\include{results}

\include{discussion}

\include{conc}


\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{thesis_1}

\end{document}
```

Here is how I add a picture:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Pictures/DAC_system.jpg}
    \caption[ddfsdfsdasd \cite{fasihi2019techno}}
    \label{fig:AdsorptionD}
\end{figure}
```

I really appreciate your help!

Daniel

Comment: Most bitmap images have no reliable information about their natural size. Just use a width (or height) instead of a scale to include them, as `\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{mypicture.jpg}` which will use 90% of the current line width for the horizontal size.

Comment: is that true for jpeg and png?

Comment: You can use `width` and/or `height` with any graphic type that is supported by `\includegraphics`. Normally `eps` and `pdf` files have a natural size, though, so `scale` works, but I always recommend using the width or height and to state it proportionally to the linewidth or absolute depending on the use case (i.e., you can also say `[width=4cm]` if this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you @Rmano

Comment: Exactly which engine are you using here? It is listed in the overleaf settings for your project. This error is typically seen with jpg or png when using the latex engine instead of the normal pdflatex engine

Comment: How are you typesetting the document? Are you using latex or pdflatex?

Comment: I'm using Pdflatex